# ghost-cursor Error : elem.remoteObject is not a function in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, headless

whenever I run the script in the Local system the cursor properly worked and when I run inside docker that time I fetch an Error so anybody guid me what is wrong or whether this issue is package side or not.?

when I run in Locally that time I headless: false and Run inside docker that time headless: true but I tried inside docker headless: false but it can't work

here is code

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const {path,createCursor} = require("ghost-cursor");
const url = process.argv[2];

async function run() {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        args: ['--disable-gpu', '--no-first-run', '--no-sandbox', '--no-zygote'],
        "dumpio": true,
        "devtools": false,
        "ignoreHTTPSErrors": true,
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    const cursor = createCursor(page);
    await cursor.move(selector)
    await page.goto(url);
    await page.screenshot({ path: 'screenshot.png' });
    browser.close();
}
run();

Here is Error Message 

    TypeError: elem.remoteObject is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/app/node_modules/ghost-cursor/lib/spoof.js:458:61)
    at step (/usr/app/node_modules/ghost-cursor/lib/spoof.js:44:23)
    at Object.next (/usr/app/node_modules/ghost-cursor/lib/spoof.js:25:53)
    at fulfilled (/usr/app/node_modules/ghost-cursor/lib/spoof.js:16:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`selector` is undefined

You need to grab an element from the UI to move to like so

```
import { createCursor } from "ghost-cursor"
import puppeteer from "puppeteer"

const run = async (url) => {
  const selector = "#sign-up button"
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  const cursor = createCursor(page)
  await page.goto(url)
  await page.waitForSelector(selector)
  await cursor.click(selector)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This must be happening due to version discrepancies with the way remoteObject can be accessed. The temporary solution I arrived at was to modify the source code.

Go to `/node_modules/ghost-cursor/lib/spoof.js` and change the references from `.remoteObject().objectId` to `._remoteObject.objectId`.

Obviously modifying code from your deps is a bad idea, but I couldn't find the right solution anywhere.